# NFT royalties Cardano

Tags: nft

I am attempting to create a NFT with % royalties when NFT is re-sold.

My idea would be the following :

- The *symbolic* owner of the NFT is defined in the datum of the script e.g. datum = { owner : [ownerwallet] , ... }
- The following end points are available in the smart contract :

`A) purchase : if someone want to purchase the NFT (i.e. rename the owner par of the datum) B) define_selling_price : to define at which selling price the purchase operation will work  C) define_who_can_purchase: to ensure that if you want to sell it to someone, nobody else can purchase it (i.e. allowed purchased wallet)`

- To ensure that the royalties are paid, the validation script verifies that there are only two resulting UTXO of the "purchase" endpoint, the first UTXO contains x% of ADA to hardwritten address (i.e. royalty ) , the second UTXO is copy of the exact same script (for future selling)

Could that be done in the described way above ?
What is the exhaustive list of the parameters available for a smart validator to work?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Should one of the answers be marked as accepted?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be done. Just create a smart validator that makes sure, that when the UTXO containing the asset is spend to a new address, it also requires an additional input for the royalty address.

I believe you are correct in your second question.

Comment: sorry I just rewrote my question with more details ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap a native asset into a tailored smart contract, but I think this only makes sense if you also provide the platform to interact with these smart contracts. It is not a sell-and-forget transaction where the buyer can do whatever he wants including using DEXs to trade his asset.